# Reshaping image for tensor flow computation graph

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to build computation graph first time  for image classification . 
While preparing/experimention  for Input I do this preprocessing

```
image = tf.read_file('DSC_0367.JPG')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [64, 64])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 12228))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(image)))
```

I get shape of image [64 64  3]
is my understanding correct that before feeding to computation graph I need to create a vector of input image data which is of dimension N x 1 
where N is 64 * 64 * 3 =  12228 .

if yes and when  I try to reshape image with

```
image = tf.reshape(image, [12228])
```

I get an error

> ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 12288 elements to shape
>   [12228] (12228 elements) for 'Reshape_12' (op: 'Reshape') with input
>   shapes: [64,64,3], [1] and with input tensors computed as partial
>   shapes: input[1] = [12228].

below this I define my hidden layer 1 as tgis

```
w =  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([12228, 100])
b =  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100])
```

Comment: `64 * 64 * 3` = `12288` instead of `12228`.

Comment: oops !! silly mistake .. thanks !!